# Unable to get data

Tags: json, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, angularjs-ng-repeat

hope all is well!

I am starting out with AngularJS and having some trouble with the $http usage.
I have been scouring for the last four hours or so trying to figure this out without luck.

This is the code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Whois Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" ng-app="App">
 <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="answer in answers"></li>
     {{answer}}
 </ul>


 <script>

 angular.module('App', [])
         .controller('Controller', function($scope, $http){

             $http.get('http://api.statdns.com/statdns.net/mx').success(function(data){
                    $scope.answer = data;
             });
         });
  </script>
  </div>
  </body>
```

What I need it to do is to check the url given and then pull the information from the "answer":
section and display that data. Ultimately I want to be able for the user to input the url to parse themselves such as.

$http.get('http://api.statdns.com/{{query}}/mx')

Any help to get me on the right track would be extremely appreciated and helpful.

Comment: Please explain -  Ultimately I want to be able for the user to input the url to parse themselves such as $http.get('http://api.statdns.com/{{query}}/mx')

Comment: This means that is the final goal of the application, however I want to focus first on getting the page to load the json data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-repeat` is used to iterate over a JavaScript array. but the data at http://api.statdns.com/statdns.net/mx doesn't seem to be an array:

```
{
    "question": [ {...} ],
    "answer": [ {...} ],
    "authority": [ {...} ],
    "additional": [ {...} ],
}
```

did you mean to iterate over answers? like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="answer in answers.answer">
        {{answer}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello Raghav! I am looking to pull all the data from Answer:

such as:

 {
            "name": "statdns.net.",
            "type": "MX",
            "class": "IN",
            "ttl": 600,
            "rdlength": 4,
            "rdata": "10 statdns.net."
        }

So I want the site to show all this information within a table, I can add the html table later, just looking to get the information parsed at the moment.

Comment: Here you go: http://plnkr.co/edit/vKR9vrclsk5v5eCdY1Gl
I have added a grid and defined the fields in hopes of the data populating,  with no results.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.statdns.com/statdns.net/mx. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` If you own that url, try adding CORS headers.

Comment: Also you don't have your data structured the way `ng-grid` wants you to provide. It needs an array of objects. See this plunker demo. http://plnkr.co/edit/hLZXrQShHcSFXA7KuqOM?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! It makes complete sense now!

Answer (score 1):

you have done a mistake . 
`$scope.answer = data;` should be `$scope.answers = data;`

update:

```
<ul ng-controller="Controller">
     <li ng-repeat="answer in answers"> {{answer}}</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! It still appears to be coming back a blank page for me. http://coffeeafterdark.com/app/test.html is the link to the app. I did notice that the {{answer}} was outside of the li, I put it in however no luck still. I think I'd be happy with it to even show the json data at all.

Comment: you have missed out adding the controller. I too missed pointing it out :).

Comment: Yes definitely does appear I had left out the controller. I have added it with still the same results. I know there is likely something I am missing out. I think I will goto sleep on it and hopefully it comes to me. Thanks so much for the help Rabi.